# return value from defered.then()

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, deferred

I want to get the value returned by ajax call in `variable x` without making the ajax call synchronus. How can I achieve this?

```
  foo = function() {
        var x = foo1(); 
        // var x is always undefined
  }

  foo1 = function() {
      var deferred = foo2();
      deferred.then(function(response) { return response; });
  }

  foo2 = function() {
      return dojo.xhrGet(); // ajax call
  }
```

Comment: No matter how many functions you create and how many promises you wrap, you'll never get the value outside of the callback.

Comment: So, how to deal with a situation, where a function requires data from an ajax call. So, it is calling another function where the ajax call is implemented?

Comment: By either having it accept a callback, or by having it return a promise

Comment: Here I am returning the  a deferred in foo2 . So, how can use deferred's then function to either use the response in function foo1 or return the response to function foo.

Comment: `foo = function (){ return foo1(); } `

Comment: `foo1 = function() {
      var deferred = foo2();
      return deferred.then(function(response) { return response; });
  }`

Comment: but, all of this can be simplified to: `foo2().then(function () { /* all done!*/ });` the rest is redundant.